# Cleanup CDC table once changes (insert/update) effected destination table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

CDC:
I have enabled CDC on a table called ABC. 
Whatever insertion/ update occur in that ABC table , cdc_ABC table is holding. 
SSIS Package:
Now thing is that in SSIS Package I gave ‘cdc_ABC ‘ table as source.
From that source, OLEDB Command /OLEDB Destination will update / insert records into destination table respectively.
This package runs for every 10 minutes.

Issue:
Is there any best way to cleanup CDC Table once it is updated to Destination table?

Answer (score 0):

CDC supports only time based cleanup. See  [Administer and Monitor Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645592.aspx#Cleanup):

> For the cleanup job, the possibility for customization is in the
>   strategy used to determine which change table entries are to be
>   discarded. **The only supported strategy in the delivered cleanup job is
>   a time-based one**.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply !!
But i want restrict records which are already updated to destination. So is there way to do that ?

Comment: Your copy job must keep track of what was copied and what was not. You must use the LSN columns, that's why they're  there. You need to read the basics, see [Work with Change Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645858.aspx).